# Parsing a malformed CSV file

Tags: php, csv

How can I parse a CSV like this one in PHP (there's a double quote near `value 8`)?

```
"03720108";"value 8"";"";"219";"03720108";"value";"value";"value";"";"";"";"";"";"";"value";"";"";"value";"value";
```

I tried with `fgetscv($pointer, 4096, ';', '"');`

Comment: You answered it yourself with `there's a double quotes near 'value 8'`

Comment: so i was right :(? that extra quote is evil.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Notice the extra quote.

> "value 8"";

Answer (score 0):

Your data seems to be malformed starting at the prior line.  You have an opening quote with no closing quote.

Comment: I was viewing your original version prior to @Macmade's edits.  It appeared to have two lines.

Comment: Yeah... it must have word-wrapped.  Pretty sharp of @Macmade to notice and fix it that fast.

Answer (score 0):

You might still be able to parse this string, though:

```
$str = '"03720108";"value 8"";"";"219";"03720108";"value";"value";"value";"";"";"";"";"";"";"value";"";"";"value";"value";';

$parsed = array_map(
  function( $str ) { return substr($str, 1, -1); },
  explode(';', $str)
);

var_export($parsed);
/*
  array (
    0 => '03720108',
    1 => 'value 8"',
    2 => '',
    3 => '219',
    4 => '03720108',
    5 => 'value',
    6 => 'value',
    7 => 'value',
    8 => '',
    9 => '',
    10 => '',
    11 => '',
    12 => '',
    13 => '',
    14 => 'value',
    15 => '',
    16 => '',
    17 => 'value',
    18 => 'value',
    19 => false,
  )
 */
```

Things get a bit more complicated, though, if there are elements that contain a `;` character (normally would be escaped by enclosing the value in quotes... d'oh!), and the above code assumes that you only need to parse a single line (though if you are using [`fgets()`](http://php.net/fgets) to read the input stream, you should be OK).